# Derivation of the Force Law predicted by General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, approximations

I was reading a book where Precession of Mercury's perihelion was described using general relativity. There I found the following equation:

$$
F \approx \frac{G M_m M_s}{r^2}\left(1+\frac{\alpha}{r^2}\right)
$$
Where $\alpha$, he states to be expressed by speed of light, mass of sun, eccentricity of the orbit. This equation seems to be an extension of Newton's Gravitational Law but the author didn't specify how the equation came. Can anyone provide with the derivation of this equation or any reference?

Comment: Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-Newtonian_expansion although that article doesn't go into much detail.

Comment: Could you provide reference for the expression you cite? It is different from the usual post-Newtonian approximation provided in the Q&A indicated as duplicate by @JohnRennie and it is not explicitely contained in the wikipedia page cited by PM2Ring   If it is really different it could be a case for reopening your question.

Comment: The book is **Computational Physics by Nicholas J. Giordano and Hisao Nakanishi 2nd Edition**. It's mentioned in section 4.3, page 108

Comment: I do not have access to that book. However, I think the formula you cite is wrong. The first correction to Newton's formula should go like $1/r^3$ and not $1/r^4$.